# Find and report line numbers of empty lines in text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have text file containing 14000+ lines. it contains some data I am using for data training of speech recognition.

I created that file via coding of java and due to some semantic error a few of the lines are empty. Every time I run training it gives an error after about 30 minutes complaining that there is a empty line.

Is there any code/script/command which can give me list of line numbers with empty lines, so I can fill those empty lines and save my time?

Working should be like:

I will input a `file.txt` and it will give me

`line number 1121,1212,1450,13000 and so on ...`  are empty in `file.txt`

[image]

Comment: I removed the references to 16.10 as this question is not specific to the Ubuntu release, but please do upgrade as 16.10 is now unsupported (and off-topic here)

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem; *how* are you going to fill the empty lines once you have the list?

Comment: `sed -i '/^$/d' file` will _delete_ empty lines from `file`. It might be a better solution to just print line numbers...

Comment: i dont want to remove empty line but rather fill them with correct values

Answer (score 17):

You can find the empty lines, and their line numbers, with

```
grep -E --line-number --with-filename '^$' file.txt
```

An example:

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ grep -E --line-number --with-filename '^$' file.txt
file.txt:1:
file.txt:3:
file.txt:4:
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ cat -n file.txt
     1  
     2  Not empty
     3  
     4  
     5  Not empty
w3@aardvark:~(0)$
```

If your "empty" lines contain blanks or TABs, use:

```
grep -E --line-number --with-filename '^\s*$' file.txt
```

Comment: Why are you using `-E`? nice although +1 ;)

Comment: Also does the job: `grep -n '^$' file.txt`. If you want just the numbers, pipe into `cut -d: -f1`.

Comment: @Ravexina There used to be several `grep` programs (`grep`, `egrep`, `fgrep`), but modern programming has combined them into one (and it's the POSIX standard). `-E` tells `grep` to `Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression`, e.g., behave like the old `egrep`.

Comment: @waltinator I think what Ravexina is wondering is why you need `-E` for  a simple pattern like `^$`.

Comment: Yeah, as muru states that, you are not using any ERE, at least in your first command, that was my actual question ...

Answer (score 7):

`sed` will report the line number with the `=` command, so you can use this expression to report line numbers of empty lines (lines with nothing between `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line)):

```
sed -n '/^$/=' file
```

We use the `-n` option to suppress printing the stream (line numbers are printed separately from the lines themselves when we use `=`, so there is no `p` command here), so the only output is line numbers of the matching lines.

```
$ sed -n '/^$/=' foo 
1
3
5
7
```

(if lines 1, 3 , 5 and 7 are empty in `foo`)

---

Here's an example to show how you can get the user interaction you wanted. You could use any solution in place of the `sed` expression in these structures...

```
$ cat foo

2

4

6

8
```

So:

```
$ read -p "Enter file name: "; echo -e "The following lines are empty in "$REPLY":\n$(sed -n '/^$/=' "$REPLY" | tr '\n' ' ')"
Enter file name: foo
The following lines are empty in foo:
1 3 5 7
```

(Use `tr '\n' ','` to get commas instead of spaces)

You could save as a script (I'm naming mine `empline`):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter file name: "
echo -e "The following lines are empty in "$REPLY":\n\
$(sed -n '/^$/=' "$REPLY" | tr '\n' ' ')"
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x empline
```

Then you can run it like this

```
$ ./empline
Enter file name: foo
The following lines are empty in foo:
1 3 5 7
```

You could skip the `read` line and replace `"$REPLY"` with `"$1"` to use the filename as a positional parameter (so run `./empline foo`). To simplify usage, you could make a function and add to the end of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function empline() {
    echo -e "The following lines are empty in "$1":\n\
$(sed -n '/^$/=' "$1" | tr '\n' ' ')"
}
```

This takes the filename as argument:

```
$ empline foo
The following lines are empty in foo:
1 3 5 7
```

Comment: sed -n '/^$/=' file 
its not working

Comment: Did you give the correct file name? Are there any characters at all on the empty lines? @AdnanAli

Answer (score 6):

## Using `awk`

The method for **multiple file input** (see end of post) is the most robust.

### Single file input:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "Line numbers of empty lines in " ARGV[1] ": " } !NF { printf sep NR ; sep="," } END { printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

The `BEGIN` section runs before the input file is processed.

`ARGV[1]` is the name of the input file.  This corresponds to awk's `FILENAME` variable, which does not work in the `BEGIN` section.

`!NF` matches lines that are blank or that only contain field separators.  The default field separators are space and tab characters, so lines that contain only spaces and tabs count as empty.  `NF` (without the exclamation point) matches lines that *contain* data, and adding `!` *inverts* the match.

`NR` is the input file's line number currently being evaluated.  **`NR` does not reset to 1 if additional input files are specified on the command line.**

To prevent a comma from appearing in front of the first matching line number, leave the string `sep` undefined until after printing the first match.

The `END` section runs after the input file is processed.  In this example, it terminates the output cleanly by printing a Unix-style newline character.

Example output:

```
Line numbers of empty lines in file.txt: 8,13,15,20,25,28
```

It's a bit sloppy to use a string name without first setting it, even if you initially *want* it to be empty.  You could explicitly set the `sep` string to be empty in the `BEGIN` section:

```
awk 'BEGIN { sep="" ; printf "Line numbers of empty lines in " ARGV[1] ": " } !NF { printf sep NR ; sep="," } END { printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

### Multiple file input:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR>1 { printf "\n" } FNR==1 { sep="" ; printf "Line numbers of empty lines in " FILENAME ": " } !NF { printf sep FNR ; sep="," } END { printf "\n" }' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

`FNR` is similar to `NR`, except that the `FNR` line number counter resets to 1 at the start of each file.

The section `FNR==1 && NR>1 { printf "\n" }` causes each file's output to print on a separate line.  It prints a newline character when the first line of each *additional* input file is processed, but not for the first line of the *first* file.

Example output:

```
Line numbers of empty lines in file1.txt: 8,13,15,20,25,28
Line numbers of empty lines in file2.txt: 1,2,4,6,7,9,10
Line numbers of empty lines in file3.txt: 3,8,9,11,13,15
```

Comment: I'd probably use `FNR == 1` and `FILENAME` instead of `BEGIN` and `ARGV[1]` (and `FNR` instead of `NR`, then it should work with multiple files).

Comment: @muru - Thank you!  I've added a method for multiple file input based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Pure Bash, using the example file `foo` from [Zanna's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/943635/301745):

```
i=0
while read line; do
    ((++i))
    if [[ $line == '' ]]; then
        echo $i
    fi
done < foo
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
```

Or you might prefer the Bash equivalent of the [Python solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/943730/301745) using `enumerate()`:

```
cat -n foo | 
    while read -r i line; do
       if [[ $line == '' ]]; then
            echo $i
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 3):

**`perl`**:

Printing (`printf("%s\n", $.)`) the line number if it's empty (`if /^$/`):

```perl
perl -ne 'printf("%s\n", $.) if /^$/' file.txt
```

---

**`python3`:**

Iterating over the enumerated (`start == 1`) lines of the file, and printing the line number when empty:

```py
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if line.rstrip('\n') == "":
            print(idx)
```

Comment: i dont know how to run perl scripts in ubuntu

Comment: @AdnanAli `perl` comes by-default with Ubuntu. In your use case here, just run the way i've done, or if you fancy, use a script with `#!/usr/bin/env perl` being the shebang.

Comment: it shows nothing. I just checked. perl script is not working

Comment: @AdnanAli Please edit your question and add a sample input.

Answer (score 2):

For a single file run:

```
$ printf "line numbers %s are empty in your file.\n"\
 "$(grep --line-number '^$' file-name | tr ':\n' ', ')"
```

Which outputs:

```
line numbers 2, 5, 7, 9, 10,  are empty in your file.
```